# Easier way of retrieving an Azure VM's Public IP address

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm

Using the name/resource group of a specific VM, I'm trying to get the VM's public IP address.

This code *works* but it seems unwieldy in comparison to other AzureRM cmdlets.

```
$VM = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup -Name MyVMName
$NIC = $VM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id -replace '.*\/'
$NI = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NIC -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup
$NIIC = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -NetworkInterface $NI
$PIP = $NIIC.PublicIpAddress.Id -replace '.*\/'
$PIP = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $PIP -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup
$PIP.IpAddress
```

Is there a quicker/easier/shorter way of accessing this information?

Comment: i dont think there's an easier way

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Or there is something wrong with the solution? I also can provide more help if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. This script will list all VMs PIP in your Azure cloud.

**OLD**

```
$VM_int = Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=resourcetype 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'"
foreach($int in $VM_int){
$vmName = $int.Name
$ipAddress= (Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $int.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object { $_.IpConfiguration.Id -like "*$vmName*" })
$vmName + ' --- ' + $ipAddress.IpAddress
}
```

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, Get-AzVM doesn't provide the Public IP address of VM, but we can scrape its Network Interface Name and make a wildcard search of it through all assigned Public IPs which NIC name are matched.
It's not fast but will provide with correct results.

```
$array = @()
foreach ($vm in Get-AzVM) {
    $vmNicName = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id.Split("/")[8]
    $ipAddress = Get-AzPublicIpAddress | Where-Object {$_.IpConfiguration.Id -like "*$vmNicName*"}
    if ($null -ne $ipAddress) {
        $pipInput = New-Object psobject -Property @{
            VM       = $vm.Name
            PublicIP = $ipAddress.IpAddress
        }
        $array += $pipInput
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know, Not Yet for PowerShell.  But you can use Azure CLI

`az vm list-ip-addresses -n <VMName> -g <ResourceGroup> | grep publicIpAddresses`

[image]

Comment: actually, the grep argument is 'ipAddress'

Answer (score 2):

Try the Azure CLI command:

```
az vm list-ip-addresses -g groupName -n vmName --query "[].virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses[*].ipAddress" -o tsv
```

Or the PowerShell command just filter with your vm name:

```
$ipAddress= (Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName groupName | Where-Object { $_.IpConfiguration.Id -like "*vmName*" }
)
$ipAddress.IpAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i got the value for my Linux VM's was using below code.

```
Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName <yourRG> -Name <yourVMName> | Select-Object {$_.IpAddress}
```

This will return something of this sort:

```
$_.IpAddress
------------
52.170.56.60
```

Answer (score 0):

This outputs a bit of information however the public IP address is in there.

```
Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*MyVMName*" }
```

Or you can do this to just get the IP address:

```
Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*MyVMName*" } | Select-Object { $_.IpAddress }
```

Output is like:

```
$_.IpAddress 
--------------
13.255.162.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also match the AzPublicIpAddress IpConfiguration.Id with the VM's NetworkInterfaces.Id:

```
Get-AzPublicIpAddress | ?{$_.IpConfiguration.Id -match "$((Get-AzVM -Name $computername).NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id).*" }
```

Answer (score 0):

#Get the VM object
$vm = Get-AzVM -Name $vmName -Status

#Get name of network adapter object attached to VM
$NetworkInterfaceName = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id.Split("/") | Select -Last 1

#Get network adaptor object attached to VM
$NetworkInterfaceObject = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name $NetworkInterfaceName

#Get public IP Address object name attached to network adaptor object
$ipObjectName = $NetworkInterfaceObject.IpConfigurations.PublicIpAddress.Id.Split("/") | Select -Last 1

#get publivc IP Address attached to public IP Address object
$ipObject = Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName  -Name $ipObjectName

Write-Output $ipObject.IpAddress

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method from within a Linux VM.

First, install the Azure command-line tools in the VM, see [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt)

Second, execute the following in a shell on the VM:

```
az network public-ip list  --query  "[?dnsSettings.domainNameLabel=='MY_VM']"
```

where `MY_VM` is (hopefully) the host name of your VM. The command returns a multiline JSON string which is a list. Example is shown below:

```
[
  {
    "dnsSettings": {
      "domainNameLabel": "MY_VM",
      "fqdn": "my_vm.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"
    },
    "etag": "W/\"some_uuid...\"",
    ...
    "ipAddress": "AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD",

  },
  ...
]
```

How to parse the FQDN and the public IP out of this is left as an exercise to the reader :-)