# How to access localhost:8089 on Azure VM from my local pc's browser?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

I have an azure vm with gitlabrunner + locust on it for performance testing. Is it possible somehow to access VM's localhost:8089 from browser on my local pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it matters that it's running in a GitLab Runner. I'm not familiar with that. But here's a link to doc for how to open ports on an Azure VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

And an SO answer about how to get a VM's IP address.

[Easier way of retrieving an Azure VM's Public IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175426/easier-way-of-retrieving-an-azure-vms-public-ip-address#53179354)

You'll need to make sure the VM has the 8089 port exposed and then you need to be able to connect to the IP address (whether public or behind your VPN or whatnot).